# How can I extract a number from a string using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, count, selenium-chromedriver

I am doing WebScraping on the Frankfurter Allgemeine Zeitung Archiv and I need to count how many times the word 'Bürokratie' appears in their articles.
From 1st October 2018 to 31st October 2018 the word appeared 75 times. 
I have the string "75 Treffer". How can I extract the number 75 from that string using selenium?

Comment: `"75 Treffer".split(" ")[0]`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you getting an error? See [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

This code extract number any way from the string.

```
# Python3 code to demonstrate 
# getting numbers from string  
# using List comprehension + isdigit() +split() 

# initializing string  
test_string = "There are 2 Cars for 8 persons"

# printing original string  
print("The original string : " + test_string) 

# using List comprehension + isdigit() +split() 
# getting numbers from string  
res = [int(i) for i in test_string.split() if i.isdigit()] 

# print result 
print("The numbers list is : " + str(res))
```

Hope this will help you to address your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Call the split function using " " as the place to split at then cast to an int:

```
yourString = "75 whatever" 
splitString = yourString.split( ' ' )
yourInt = int( splitString[0] )
```